# $p \subset q$ are two distinct elements of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and $K=Q(R/p),$ then $K$ is not finitely generated as $R$-module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, integral-extensions

> Suppose $p \subset q$ are two distinct prime ideals of the commutative ring $R.$ Let $K$ be the quotient field of $R/p.$ Show that $K$ is not finitely generated as $R$-module.

My guess: If $K$ is finitely generated as $R$-module it would be finitely generated as $R/p$-module, hence $K$ becomes an integral extension over $R/p.$ This implies that $R/p$ is a field which is not true, since $q/p$ is an nonzero prime ideal in $R/p.$ My only doubt is why $K$ can be considered as an $R$-module ? Is it obvious ?

Comment: In fact, you have a prime ideal $p$ which is not maximal, and want to show that $R\to R/p\to Q(R/p)$ is not finite. Suppose the contrary. Then $Q(R/p)$ is a finitely generated $R/p$-module, too. All you have to show now is that $Q(A)$ is not a finitely generated $A$-module if $A$ is an integral domain which is not a field.

Comment: I just read your guess and I find right all you say. I don't know why you are surprised that $Q(R/p)$ is an $R$-module.

Comment: Yes I understand why it is. Thanks